# Dashboard links not working

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

Since yesterday, all links on the Dashboard not working. If i click one link (left menu bar), always redirect the dashboard /wp-admin/ (homepage of dashboard). I have to open a page ten times to finally get to the page I would like to open. And it is, all links present.

I have a manully installed the wordpress 4.7.2. - but nothing changed. Probably is this a plugin that can do (cache plugin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those links are supposed to show submenus. If they are not showing up, that usually means your theme has a conflict with our plugin (90% of the time, this is boostrap).

Please check our documentation about conflicts with Bootstrap as well as our FAQ entry about that.